# Как сделать полоску с помощью :before, :after?

Tags: html, scss

**Есть html:**

```
<li class="upload f_left">
    <a href="#">Upload</a>
</li>
```

**Есть scss:**

```
.upload {
    //background: #dd2425;
    .border-radius(6px);
    width: auto;
    a {
        color: #333333;
        padding: 8px 13px;
        display: block;
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

Нужно сделать, что бы под `li` была красная полоска с помощью `before`. Пробовал сделать `border-bottom`, но вот нужно именно `::before`, `::after`.

Спасибо

Comment: А зачем такие требования? У обоих псевдоэлементов поддержка браузерами хуже, чем просто `border-bottom`.

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев, откуда такие сведения про [поддержку](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)?

Comment: Ну вот нужно, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: а у вас точно css? он же не поддерживает вложенное описание селекторов

Comment: @w3lifer: В моей практике все еще очень часто пишутся ТЗ, в которых требуется поддержка от ИЕ7. Если у вас иначе, то я вам завидую =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вот SCSS:**

```
 a {
    color: #333333;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 1px;
      background: green;
    }
  }
```

**Пример**

http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/BKdjOL

Comment: так-то предоставленный код не css, напрямую в браузере вряд ли заработает

Comment: @Grundy поправил

Comment: а без бордера возможно?например, высота и ширина?

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов поправил пример

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Спасибо!

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а что за синтаксис такой вложенный: `selector1 { selector2 {} }` и `&`? Что-то не пойму, разве так можно в CSS?

Comment: @w3lifer это SCSS, удобная вещь, https://habrahabr.ru/post/140612/ . Парсится потом в CSS, конструкции получаются более удобными и приятными глазу, + можно использовать калькуляцию и переменные

Comment: @w3lifer для примера на `codepen` в блоке CSS можешь нажать на `view compiled` и увидишь, какой вид имеет скомпиленный SCSS

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов закрывай вопрос, если все правильно